# Redirecting to database table value

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I'm writing a URL shortener but having some issues.

So when the user sends a request, say *http://localhost:3000/1*, I want it to redirect to the url stored under the column *original_url* that has the *ID of 1* in my database.

Here is the function I wrote to achieve this:

```
// :id will match anything after the / in the url, and set it as the req.params.id value
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  console.log("hi you're about to match url id to database id");
  //get a prostgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    //handle connection errors
    if (err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err });
    }
    //match id in database to id from query in url
    const query = client.query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id =" + req.params.id);
    console.log("successfully matched database id value to id value in url");

    console.log(req.query);
    res.redirect(req.query);
  });
});
```

The problem is, after I match the correct ID, I don't know how to redirect the user to the url stored in my column *original_url* which contains the url to re-direct to.

How can I retrieve the value of *original_url* that corresponds to the entered ID?

[Here is my full code](http://pastebin.com/aG9qJ7yQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using node-postgres package from npm (npm i --save pg),
the results of a query are available as result.rows.  If you are finding a single row, result.rows[0].original_url would presumably have your redirect.  Also, the pg package uses the common node callback pattern.

```
client.query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = $1', [req.params.id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result.rows[0]); // outputs: { original_url: 'http://mysite.dev' };
}
```

If you are using restify server, you have to pass next to redirect.  Express does not require that.

For example with restify:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.redirect(url, next);
}
```

If the redirect url does not include a protocol (i.e. http), then the redirect will be relative to the current url path.